# Is there a risk with making my Device ID public?

Tags: android, phone, iphone, identity

When making a mobile app with ads, I am required to register my test phones as test devices by providing the Device ID.  These Device IDs are unique to an individual phone.  Is there any risk with publishing my app with the Device ID?  Or should I remove my Device ID before publishing?

Is there a risk with making my phone's Device ID public?  If so, what is it?

Added Details:

Google's AdMob requires you to add your test device ID to your code, in order to prevent false advertisement. [They suggest this code be removed before publication](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting), but so not say why. It is an inconvenience to remove it, and prevents testing on the live build. Several sources say it does not need to be removed, but Google's documentation says it does. I am trying to determine why they want this code removed. My best guess is that it may be a security risk to publicize your devices unique identifier.

Comment: with the added details, I'd ask Google: they are the ones suggesting this action (only they will understand the risks of their own product)

Comment: I Googled "google admob remove test device ID" and came up with a bunch of hits

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355821/do-i-need-to-remove-test-device-when-publishing-on-admob-android

Comment: @Schroeder So did I.  And I contacted Google.  I am not having my question answered, which is "Is there a risk with making my device ID public?"  And none of the answers I have searched for have any authority to make those claims (which go against the documentation).

Comment: Google never says it needs to be removed - it just says to remove it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The risk is privacy (the reason why Android created the advertiser ID instead) - your test device is now forever attributed to you and/or your company.

Imagine a competitor getting your app, reading the code, and seeing this ID. Then they create an app that includes code looking for this device ID, hoping you will download and use the app (and you would because they are a competitor).

Now your competitor can uniquely identify your device and gain access to whatever you enable access to and attribute it to you. What might they discover? What insights into your next apps might they glean?

In the end, all it is an ID. But the danger is positive attribution.